# Concurrently iterating over a BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

In an application which uses a `BlockingQueue`, I am facing a new requirement that can only be implemented by iterating over the elements present in the queue (to provide info about the current status of the elements in there).

According to the `API Javadoc` only the queueing methods of a BlockingQueue implementation are required to be thread-safe. `Other API methods` (eg. those inherited from the `Collection interface`) may not be used concurrently, though I am not sure whether this also applies to mere read access...

Can I safely use `iterator() WITHOUT altering the producer/consumer threads` which may normally interact with the queue at any time? I have no need for a `100% consistent iteration` (it does not matter whether I see elements added/removed while iterating the queue), but I don't want to end up with nasty `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`.

Note that the application is currently using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, but I am free to choose any other `(unbounded) BlockingQueue implementation` (including `free open-source third-party implementations`). Also, I don't want to rely on things that may break in the future, so I want a solution that is OK according to the `API` and does not just merely happen to work with the `current JRE`.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the Java 8 [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for `BlockingQueue` states this:

> `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe.

Nothing in the javadoc says<sup>1</sup> that this only applies to the methods specified in the  `BlockingQueue` API itself.

> Can I safely use iterator() WITHOUT altering the producer/consumer threads which may normally interact with the queue at any time?

Basically, yes.  The `Iterator`'s behavior in the face of concurrent modifications is specified in the implementation class javadocs.  For `LinkedBlockingQueue`, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#iterator--) specifies that the `Iterator` returned by `iterator()` is [weakly consistent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly).  That means (for example) that your application won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if the queue is modified while it is iterating, but the iteration is not guaranteed to see all queue entries.

---

<sup>1 - The javadoc mentions that the bulk operations may be non-atomic, but non-atomic does not mean non-thread-safe.  What it means here is that some other thread may observe the queue in state where some entries have been added (or removed, or whatever) and others haven't.</sup>

---

@John Vint warns:

> Keep in mind, this is as of Java 8 and can change.

If Oracle decided to alter the behavior *specified in the javadoc*, that would be an impediment to migration.  Past history shows that Sun / Oracle avoid doing that kind of thing.  (Though that doesn't mean that it cannot happen.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can iterate over the entire queue. Looking at `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue` implementations you do have a side effect. When constructing and operating the `Iterator` there are three places where full locks are acquired.

1. During construction
2. When invoking `next()`
3. When invoking `remove()`

Keep in mind, this is as of Java 8 and can change.

So, yes you do get to iterate safely, but you will effect the performace of `put`s and `offer`s.

---

Now for your question, does `BlockingQueue` offer safe iteration? The answer there is it depends on the implementation. There could be a future BlockingQueue implementation that will throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I am not worried about UnsupportedOperationExceptions. The LinkedBlockingQueue at least supports all Collection methods according to the docs, but I do realize that other implementations may not.